# how to load a csv file from on-prem to azure data lake

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have a file placed on prem-Server the file get every 10 seconds a new row, i need a way to only copy the new added row to a data lake and not alway the whole file, i use azure synapse
and there is a timestamp column on the rows
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of information on your setup, which could be subject to numerous constraints, e.g. is your file accessible from outside your network? If not, you need something to perform Outbound activities, e.g. have On-Premises Data Gateway on that machine (or another machine with access via network to that file).

Azure Synapse Integration runtime enables the concept of "self-hosted", which literally means Data Factory pipeline to run data flows (which could accommodate the "append" capability you need). Details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory

You might want to opt for alternative solutions, such as based on Azure storage with agent sync-up from on-premises, at which time Azure Synapse could directly use the online copy.

Comment: Thank you 
In fact i use a Self hosted IR to transfer data from Client Network to Data lake which works properly but as the file is growing i need to transfer Only  the new added data 
Means when my pipeline runs it should be able to identify which row has been added since the last pipeline run and only transfer them
The file is saved each time a row is added

Comment: Can you not envision naming files accordingly, e.g. copy with rename based on current processing date > process ingest > clean source. also, during ingest during mapping add a time-stamp (if none exists) which will help you later

Comment: Is it possible with synapse Features to filter a file on-prem based on timestamp because i want only to ingest the new added rows